# Algolia indexing disabled items in Craft

Tags: plugin-searchplus

We have Algolia search running on our Craft install through the Search Plus plunin. When I disable an entry I'm finding that it is still searchable through Algolia, which then results in a broken link.

Has anyone else experienced this or do you know of a way to filter out results that are disabled?

Comment: Never used the plugin before, but do you have the "enabled" property mapped so Algolia can keep track of it? https://squarebit.co.uk/software/craft/searchplus/usage/advanced-usage/custom-content-mapping